# How can i make search arrays in firebase firestore with flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[image]My code is this :

```
 String search = '';
    String searchKeys = selectedWork.toString();

    for (int i = 0; i <= searchKeys.length; i++) {
      search += searchKeys[i];
      print(search);
    }

    posts
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .collection('userPosts')
        .add(
      {
        'search': [search],
      },
    );
```

But this gives that error :
RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..15: 16)

Can someone help me to improve the search system?

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of your document structure and then explain what are you trying to query?

Comment: Hi, I want to add a search string with arrays to my firebase firestore , but when click button this give me range error like that : RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..15: 16)

Comment: I cannot see any code that is related with Firestore. Please update your question with relevant code and a screenshot of database.

Comment: okay, you can see it know

Comment: this search arrays in the screenshot was made manually by my side , but I want to make it automatically when click some action button

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < searchKeys.length; i++)`:  try `i < searchKeys.length` instead of `i <= searchKeys.length`

Comment: Thanks you)) it was help me))

Comment: I'll just mark this as a typo then :D

Comment: Good catch @Dharmaraj! 